# hide bootstrap popover on blur EXCEPT if element inside popover has focus

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap popover with a text input inside of it. I want the popover to hide if the user clicks outside of the popover, but stay open if anything inside the popover, such as the input field, receives focus.

Using the `trigger:focus` option does not work, since after the popover is shown, clicking on anything, including the popover, hides it.

I've tried adding a `$('.popover').on('blur')` function but I'm not sure how to handle checking if something inside the popover has focus when the blur event is triggered.

This fiddle illustrates the *unwanted* behaviour
http://jsfiddle.net/Lcsqjdgu/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work as you described.

1. Set the focus on the input when the popover is shown.
2. Hide the popover on blur.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aywwdvvd/)

```
$('button').on('shown.bs.popover', function() {
  $('#new_input').focus();
})

$(document).on('blur','.popover', function() {
   $(this).popover('hide');
});
```

Comment: Hi, yoru solution worked great, but I have one question, why did you put the data-animation="..." to false?

Comment: @Leo The OP had that in his example JSFiddle which I copied to create my example... that is all. I don't think it is needed for this solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using the manual trigger.  This will allow you complete control over when/how the popover is show or hidden.

```
$('#bravo').popover({
    html: true,
    trigger: 'manual',
    content: '<div class="input-group">'+
              '<input id="new_input" type="text" placeholder="My Dashboard" class="form-control">'+
              '<span class="input-group-btn">'+
                '<button class="btn btn-success btn-default" type="button">Create</button>'+
              '</span>'+
        '</div>'
});

$('#bravo').click(function() {
    $(this).popover('toggle');
});
```

[See Fidde here.](http://jsfiddle.net/gn5s2v96/)

Comment: It's default behavior. $('.popover').popover(); The question was about blur

Comment: The second example in the fiddle isn't doing what is described there.